# Groovy Class loader wont load Java class

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

I have this groovy script written in .groovy file:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;
def doit() {
    Class.forName('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'); // If i skip this line it throws SQLException no driver registered for URL
    def db = [url:'jdbc:oracle:thin:/@localhost:1555:AVDB', user:'sys as sysdba', password:'secret',driver:'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'];
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver) ;
    sql.execute 'CREATE USER RandomUser identified by Secret123';
}
```

I am calling above Groovy from Java in following way:

```
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);

Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(groovySource); // groovySource is a File object pointing to .groovy file
GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
Object[] args = {};
groovyObject.invokeMethod("doit", args);
```

**Problem**:

Class **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver** is present in Java's classpath but groovy cant find it at line: `Class.forName('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver');`

Throws ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @Reimeus Yeah, its on Java's classpath

Comment: How do you run the Java code? what is the classloader you are getting from getClass().getClassLoader()? can you share the full exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

try magic lines before groovy method:

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def doit(){....}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should simply pass java CL down into your groovy method:

```
def doit( ClassLoader cl ) {
  cl.loadClass 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
  ....
}
```

then call

```
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
Object[] args = { parent };
groovyObject.invokeMethod("doit", args);
```